# Search for punctuation and put the punctuation at the beginning of a word

Tags: javascript, regex

For Israel Hebrew locale I need to search for punctuation and put it at the beginning of the word.  For example:

"disable. fable."  should be ".disable .fable"

Here is what I have so far:

```js
var string = "disable. fable."
console.log(string.indexOf("."));
var punctuation = "disable.".slice(-1);
console.log("punctuation: " + punctuation);
string = punctuation + string;
console.log("string: " + string);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(\w+)(\.)
```

And this replacement string:

```
$2$1
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oO7sA5/1)**

Code:

```
var re = /(\w+)(\.)/g; 
var str = 'disable. fable.';
var subst = '$2$1'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);

// result: .disable .fable
```

As **[Shlomo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415661/shlomo)** pointed in this comment, if you want to cover additional signs you could use this regex:

```
(\w+)([.?,!:;])
```

Comment: You should probably use `(\w+)([.?,!:;])` to cover all punctuation.